# UILocalNotification random strings

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am creating UILocalNotifications in my app, i want to display different string every time the notification is passed. The problem is that first time it choses random string the after that it shows the same string everytime. Anyone know how to show random string every time from the list of 5 - 6 strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one workaround - schedule several notifications with different (random) strings.

Obviously, you won't be able to use repetitions, so you will be able to plan only for a limited future time (64 notifications is the limit). Usually that's not a big issue, if you reschedule notifications everytime the app is opened and the last notification is something like "You have not visited MY_APPLICATION for a while, you won't be receiving notifications any more".